# bootstrap-ui 0.12.0 popover-template not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I upgraded to bootstrap-ui version from 0.8.0 to 0.12.0 and the popover-template attribute stopped working.

```
 <a ng-if="offer.countryIds.length > 6"
    popover-placement="top"
    popover-trigger="mouseenter"
    popover-template="countries.popover.html">
         {{offer.countryIds.length}} Countries
  </a>
```

I know that the popover-template never was official and still i want to use her

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Now, you can upgrade to version 0.13.0 it work